# Rails - Given @Comments - how to obtain the 2nd to last comment w/o rehitting the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

given @comments which can contain 1 or more records. How do I obtain the 2nd to last comment?

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I suppose that would also be called the *penultimate* record:

```
@comments[-2]
```

[Here are the docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)<sup>1</sup> to Ruby's interesting index operator.

---

<sup>1. Rubyists, note how I linked this. If you take the version out of your ruby-doc links the reference will be durable and recent.</sup>

Answer (score 11):

With any Ruby array, you can specify any range or specific index, for example if you wanted every comment from the second oldest to the second newest you could do like:

```
@comments[1..-2]
```

And to get just the second to last:

```
@comments[-2]
```

Documentation for [Ruby Array#range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D)

In Rails, if you wanted the last two comments, then you could do this, which returns an array of the last two:

```
@comments.last(2)
```

Documentation for [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html)

Comment: +1 for `last(2)`. This works well when used directly on the model as well without having to preload all the records into memory, like `Comment.last(2)`.

Answer (score 8):

> can contain 1 or more records

This question is old, but for people coming to this now...

The other solutions will return nil if there is only one record. If you want to be sure to return a record use:

```
@comments.last(2)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@comments[-2]
```

This is pretty much the same as your last question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@comments = Comment.all         #Gather all comments from DB, filter as necessary.
@comments[-2]                   #Second to last comment in array
```

Comment: This is kinda wrong, if you have a huge database it will kill your memory and it would take too much time.
You can do it in the console if you have a small DB