# message.last returning different results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am seeing extremely weird results when I do .last on a list of instances. It seems to be changing. What I'm looking to do is check the second to last message that was received. Here's the output from the console that is so weird:

```
irb(main):002:0> c.messages.last
=> #<Message id: 140426, user_id: nil, customer_id: 21672, text: "My personal coupon code doesn't work ", direction: "received", created_at: "2014-08-14 14:20:47", updated_at: "2014-08-14 14:20:47", viewed: true, company_id: 2, via_api: false, error_description: nil>
irb(main):003:0> c.messages[0]
=> #<Message id: 140426, user_id: nil, customer_id: 21672, text: "My personal coupon code doesn't work ", direction: "received", created_at: "2014-08-14 14:20:47", updated_at: "2014-08-14 14:20:47", viewed: true, company_id: 2, via_api: false, error_description: nil>
irb(main):004:0> c.messages[-1]
=> #<Message id: 130979, user_id: 4, customer_id: 21672, text: "You are officially a Mayvenn! To confirm your infor...", direction: "sent", created_at: "2014-08-11 18:02:18", updated_at: "2014-08-11 18:02:18", viewed: true, company_id: 2, via_api: true, error_description: nil>
irb(main):005:0> c.messages[1]
=> #<Message id: 140371, user_id: 4, customer_id: 21672, text: "Have upcoming appointments? Make sure to text them ...", direction: "sent", created_at: "2014-08-14 14:17:51", updated_at: "2014-08-14 14:17:51", viewed: true, company_id: 2, via_api: true, error_description: nil>
irb(main):006:0> c.messages.last
=> #<Message id: 130979, user_id: 4, customer_id: 21672, text: "You are officially signed up! To confirm your infor...", direction: "sent", created_at: "2014-08-11 18:02:18", updated_at: "2014-08-11 18:02:18", viewed: true, company_id: 2, via_api: true, error_description: nil>
```

the "you are officially signed up!" message is the first message this user received and the "My personal coupon code..." is the last. what am i doing wrong here?

How do I get the second to last message consistently?

Comment: What's the sql that gets generated?

Comment: not sure but this is what the .last method does: Find the last record (or last N records if a parameter is supplied). If no order is defined it will order by primary key. And, it looks like it's NOT returning the last by primary key

Comment: guessing, but I think that messages is probably pulling from a cache of the object affiliation that is stored in a hash in-memory. When you do the -1, it is moving to the last position? If you tried resetting it after your [-1] I bet it would show the original result.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707507/rails-given-comments-how-to-obtain-the-2nd-to-last-comment-w-o-rehitting-th). You should be able to pull `c.messages[-2]` and retrieve the penultimate (second to last) message and it should be the same every time (unless underlying association or objects changes).